Mapping an entity abstract property in doctrine
I need some help mapping a model in XML.

I have an entity "Record" which have a property of type Assistant, Assistant being abstract.

There are 2 implementations of Assistant. Assistant specific implementation selection depends on "type" field in record table.


Class Record{
    Assistant $assistant;
}

Abstract class Assistant{
    string $name;
}

class Foo extends Assistant{}

class Bar extends Assistant{}

-----

Record table

- record_id
- assistant_name
- assistant_type

I need some helping finding the way to map this relationship in doctrine. I couldnt find any way to make an embeddable abstract.
I need an xml mapping. I tried something like...
<entity table="record">
    <id name="record_i"/>
    <embedded name="assistant"/>
</entity>

-----

<embeddable name="Assistant">
    <mapped-superclass name="Assistant">
    <discriminator-map>
        <discriminator-mapping value="foo_type" class="Foo" />
        <discriminator-mapping value="bar_type" class="Bar" />
    </discriminator-map>
    <field name="name"/>
</embeddable>

... And any sorts of combinations with no luck.

I cant seem to use custom fieldType bc it can only map 1 property to 1 db field

I thought about using a custom hydrator but it seems overkilling

I cant modify the model

Using doctrine-orm:2 and doctrine-dbal:3


Can someone give me a path to follow?
Thank you so much.
